# Database.update opt_allOrNone is not working on wrong Id

Tags: apex, dml, exception

I'm trying to update a list of records and I need to update the records that pass the validation rules, and get the errors for not updated rows.

I'm using this code that works fine for non Id fields:

```
List<Database.SaveResult> resultList  = Database.update(listToUpsert, false);
```

However, I'm getting an exception when some record has a invalid Id. In addition the right records are not been updated when one Id is wrong.

Exception message:  `Invalid id: 001g0000a`

How can I avoid this exception without a loop to update one by one using a try (I know this suck's but I dont see other chance) ?

### Update

As Andrew and amator comment, the solution is to wrapper the listToUpser build using a try to remove wrongs Ids.

This is my working final code:

```
                    Account a;
            List<Account> listToUpsert = new List<Account>();
            Map<String, Object> o;
            for(Object ol:listOk){
                try{
                    o =(Map<String, Object>) ol;
                    a = new Account(Id=(String)o.get('idSalesforce'));
                    a.idExternal__c = (String)o.get('idExternal');

                    listToUpsert.add(a);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    //TODO: do something on wrong Id format
                }
            }

            List<Database.SaveResult> resultList  = Database.update(listToUpsert, false);
```

Comment: Can you add details on the exception your getting please.

Comment: I've added the exception message @AndrewFawcett, but It is not saying to much

Comment: If your getting an actual Apex exception this means their is something so significantly wrong with the records your passing in, it is likely Salesforce has not started to process them at all. So its failing some kind of precheck. The Id looks odd, its not the usual 15/18 length. How is listToUpsert built? Have you tried stripping back how your populating the fields on the records in this list and the records in it, to see if you can isolate the problem?

Comment: Thank you @AndrewFawcett for your comment, it was really clear. I updated my question with additional information.

Comment: Well, in my case, I see allOrNone not working, and the whole operation failing because of missing required fields on some records..  i'm using api though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` stated in the exception, `Invalid id: 001g0000a`, is indeed wrong:  the string `001g0000a` is not in a 15- or 18-digit format.  An exception is thrown at run-time if an `id` variable is set to something with an incorrect format.

Try correcting the `id`s and add an **Update** to your question with additional information if you need more help.